# Empty table in Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to use the [Datepicker component](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) from the Angular UI Bootstrap library.

Is there a simple explanation for why I'm getting an empty table in my Datepicker component? It's being triggered correctly with `click` on the datepicker-input above, and I can't see any errors in console.

[image]

Comment: strange...try to replicate in a demo

Comment: Got the exact same issue, tried using a updated Bootstrap 3 version of the directive but same problem. Let me know if you find a solution, I will leave a answer if i do!

Comment: @ninja Good to know others have the same problem. I'll update the question as soon as I know something.

Comment: have same problem, using table version instead of dropdown version for now.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say what of the many things I did that actually solved this for me, but one notable change I made was to use angular v. 1.2.8 (I was on 1.2.0-rc2).

I as also on angular-ui-bootstrap v. 0.9.0, so I updated that to 0.10.0.

I use bower, so these changes were fairly trivial.

Now to ensure other things aren't broken as a result.

Answer (score -1):

There is a working native implementation in [AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap) rewritten from the ground up for `Bootstrap3` that leverages `ngAnimate` from AngularJS v1.2+

- Demo : http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepicker

You may also want to checkout:

- Source : https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/datepicker/datepicker.js
- Plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/sjEnF6MAFvSaOm2eP2Q1?p=preview